# Setting the initial values of a UIView animation

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiviewanimation

I run this code when a swipe event is fired, it shows an arrow zooming in while fading out, as you see I set the location of the image to be the same location as where the swipe is, but it only starts from where the previous touch was(set in the completion block). But at the start of the method I set update the location so why is it animating from the location of the previous touch?

```
    static bool isAnimating;
- (void)animateImageZoom: (UIImageView *)imageView startingAtLocation:(CGPoint)location inDirection: (FadeDirection)direction
{
    if (!isAnimating) {
        CGRect previousFrame = imageView.frame;
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, previousFrame.size.width, previousFrame.size.height);
        imageView.hidden = NO;


        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f
                              delay:0.3f
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^(void) {
                             isAnimating = YES;
                             imageView.alpha = 0;

                             // ZOOM
                             if (direction == fadeLeft) {
                                 imageView.frame = CGRectMake(location.x,
                                                              location.y, 256, 256);
                             } else if (direction == fadeRight) {
                                 imageView.frame = CGRectMake(location.x,
                                                              location.y, 256, 256);
                             }
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             isAnimating = NO;

                             imageView.frame = CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, previousFrame.size.width, previousFrame.size.height);
                             imageView.hidden = YES;
                             imageView.alpha = 0.8f;
                         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, your code AND explanation are not very clear. Where do you call this method from? can you show that code as well? Is your problem that location.x and location.y are not what you expect them to be?

Comment: It´s run when there is a swipe gesture, I want the UIImage location to be the same location as were the swipe started, but instead it is the location of the previous swipe and then animates to the position of the new swipe.